# Jquery Validate Input Box before allowing pagination button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two scripts handling my multistep form. The first handles the visibility of each step (input/selector boxes) within the form along with the visibility of the pagination buttons (prev, next).

This looks like:

```js
const previousButton = document.querySelector('#prev')
const nextButton = document.querySelector('#next')
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit')
const tabTargets = document.querySelectorAll('.tab')
const tabPanels = document.querySelectorAll('.tabpanel')
const isEmpty = (str) => !str.trim().length
let currentStep = 0

// Validate first input on load
validateEntry()

// Next: Change UI relative to current step and account for button permissions
nextButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()

  // Hide current tab
  tabPanels[currentStep].classList.add('hidden')
  tabTargets[currentStep].classList.remove('active')

  // Show next tab
  tabPanels[currentStep + 1].classList.remove('hidden')
  tabTargets[currentStep + 1].classList.add('active')
  currentStep += 1

  validateEntry()
  updateStatusDisplay()
})

// Previous: Change UI relative to current step and account for button permissions
previousButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()

  // Hide current tab
  tabPanels[currentStep].classList.add('hidden')
  tabTargets[currentStep].classList.remove('active')

  // Show previous tab
  tabPanels[currentStep - 1].classList.remove('hidden')
  tabTargets[currentStep - 1].classList.add('active')
  currentStep -= 1

  nextButton.removeAttribute('disabled')
  updateStatusDisplay()
})

function updateStatusDisplay() {
  // If on the last step, hide the next button and show submit
  if (currentStep === tabTargets.length - 1) {
    nextButton.classList.add('hidden')
    previousButton.classList.remove('hidden')
    submitButton.classList.remove('hidden')
    validateEntry()

    // If it's the first step hide the previous button
  } 
  else if (currentStep == 0) {
    nextButton.classList.remove('hidden')
    previousButton.classList.add('hidden')
    submitButton.classList.add('hidden')
    // In all other instances display both buttons
  } 
  else {
    nextButton.classList.remove('hidden')
    previousButton.classList.remove('hidden')
    submitButton.classList.add('hidden')
  }
}

function validateEntry() {
  let input = tabPanels[currentStep].querySelector('.form-input')

  // Start but disabling continue button
  nextButton.setAttribute('disabled', true)
  submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', true)

  // Validate on initial function fire
  setButtonPermissions(input)

  // Validate on input
  input.addEventListener('input', () => setButtonPermissions(input))
  // Validate if bluring from input
  input.addEventListener('blur', () => setButtonPermissions(input))
}

function setButtonPermissions(input) {
  if (isEmpty(input.value)) {
    nextButton.setAttribute('disabled', true)
    submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', true)
  } 
  else {
    nextButton.removeAttribute('disabled')
    submitButton.removeAttribute('disabled')
  }
}
```

For the first input box, i have a Jquery autocomplete which pulls data from a json file and presents it as a select option.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'Get',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: true,
    url: "AvailableFeatures.json",
    success: function(data) {
      var array = $.map(data.Table, function(item) {
        return {
          label: item.label,
          value: item.label
        }
      });

      $("#txtfeature").autocomplete({
        source: array,
        minLength: 3,
        open: function() {},
        close: function() {},
        focus: function(event, ui) {},
        select: function(event, ui) {},
        change: function(event, ui) {
          if (!ui.item) {
            $("#txtfeature").val("");
          }
        }
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {}
  });
});
```

I had been using the change event to limit the content of the input box to an item selected and if a user clicks elsewhere and the data isn't as per the selected option, it empties the content of the input box.

The problem I have is that if a user types random text in the box and simply hits continue on the form, it blanks the field but continues on to the next input box.

How can i prevent this from occurring?

Should i even have two scripts handling this form/autocomplete?

I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing what i'm trying to achieve but i'm a novice in this space and trying to learn whilst trying to build upon an idea.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like HTML and CSS in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: By the way there are no semicolons in the first code snippet...